# How to choose a application without using the mouse in Lion Mission Control?

Tags: macos, mission-control

While using Mission Control and pressing <kbd>Control ⌃</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>, I get the tiled view of all the applications in that particular desktop. Is there a keyboard shortcut to choose an application in this view?

Comment: [A similar question at Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/313055/how-to-make-mission-control-keyboard-friendly)

Comment: I tried a variety of key combos but to no avail. I'm not sure that it is possible...

Comment: I think so too. Thank you @Jonathan. I will keep this question open and will try to see if there are other workarounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try hyperswitch (https://bahoom.com/hyperswitch) - you can switch between windows only from current desktop.

Answer (score 3):

No.  I haven't found any, but that's not surprising.  Mission Control was provided for mouse / touch interaction.  Have you tried using <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> for app switching and <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>for window switching?

They are much more efficient if you're interested in keeping your hands on the keys.

Comment: Command + Tab switches over all the open application. If there is a way to sandbox that behavior to a particular desktop, it will be much more useful. It is also surprising that there is a lack of consistency. Arrow keys works, while working with multiple windows of same application.

Comment: Okay.  Now that *is* doable.  Visit System Preferences-> Mission Control and uncheck **When Switching to an application, switch to a space with open windows for the application**. See [this SuperUser link](http://superuser.com/questions/436904/how-to-auto-select-only-window-in-expose-osx-lion) for more details.

Comment: For window switching on a German keyboard, use Command + >

Comment: @uncaught_exceptions try HyperSwitch - you can switch between windows only from current desktop

Comment: @SuitUp, can you make it an answer? I think it needs to be the accepted answer

Comment: @uncaught_exceptions sure thing

Answer (score 0):

You can type the name of the window (not the name of the app) and it will select the windows in mission control that matchs. What I don't know how to swicth between all the coincidences.

Comment: It doesn't work on el capitan, right? :/