# Switch windows in Mission control with the keyboard

Tags: keyboard, mission-control

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to choose a application without using the mouse in Lion Mission Control?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54403/how-to-choose-a-application-without-using-the-mouse-in-lion-mission-control)

Is there any way so switch between windows in Mission Control without using the mouse?

In exposé you were able to switch windows with the arrow keys, but in Mission Control is not possible, even disabling the "Group windows" setting.

Comment: Thanks Lri, should I delete this question?